# partial specialization of the templates in c++

Tags: c++, templates

is it possible to do in c++ something like that:

```
template<class T1, class T2>
  class A<T1*, T2> {
    T1* var;
    T2 var1;

};

template<class T1, class T2>
  class A<T1, T2*> {
    T1 var;
    T2* var1;

};
```

Actually I want to know if I can reach template overloading, when two classes have the same name but different arguments in template, thanks in advance for any good idea

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's known as *partial template specialization*

```
template<class T1, class T2>
class A;

template<class T1, class T2>
class A<T1*, T2> {
    T1* var;
    T2 var1;
};

template<class T1, class T2>
class A<T1, T2*> {
    T1 var;
    T2* var1;
};
```

Of course, you need a third one for `A<T1*, T2*>` to play safe. Otherwise you will get an ambiguity of both are pointers.

Comment: Yes.  The key detail here, which you show but don't call out explicitly, is that you need to declare the fully-generic form of the class first (this is the first two lines of the code sample) even if you don't define it.  The original code in the question won't work because the second definition of A is not a specialization of anything that came before it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know the type without pointer you can use `boost::type_traits`:

```
#include <boost/type_traits.hpp>

template<class T1, class T2>
class A {
  typedef boost::remove_pointer<T1>::type T1_type;
  typedef boost::remove_pointer<T2>::type T2_type;
  T1_type *var;
  T2_type *var1;
};
```

`remove_pointer` template is easy to write on your own:

```
template<class T> 
struct remove_pointer{
  typedef T type;
};

template<class T>
struct remove_pointer<T*>{
  typedef T type; 
  //or even 
  typedef remove_pointer<T>::type type;
};
```

Comment: What if I write `remove_pointer<char****>`? Will it give me `char`? You need to recurse in the specialization!

Comment: @Nawaz: You're right, but sometimes it's not required. You may give `char **` (as table of strings) and want to make pointer to string in your class, not a pointer to `char`.

Comment: that is a different thing altogether, since sometimes you don't even need `remove_pointer<>`. Alright. So if you think `remove_pointer<>` really removes pointer-ness from the `T`, giving back the pointer-less type; then your implementation is not doing this; that is all I wanted to say. :-)

Comment: @Nawaz: In the question he doesn't seem to need to remove pointer-ness of type, just remove one layer of pointer. IMHO it's better to remove it that way and not to specialize template with every combination.